# How to check for number from a list without detecting numbers that have the same digits?

Tags: python

Say I have a list: `[2 dogs play, 4 dogs play, 22 dogs play, 24 dogs play, 26 dogs play]`
I have an expression that asks a user for a number and it's stored in the variable, `num`

I have a condition in my code where,

```
for item in list:
     if num in item:
        ....
        do something to item
```

My problem is that if the user inputs 2, the code will also do something to the items that have 22, 24, and 26 because it has 2 in it, when I only want it to do something to the item that has only 2. How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Your if statement won't trigger on the number 22 if you enter the integer 2 as the check. Not sure what the problem is here?

Comment: Sprung, post the full code that shows the problem. The code you've given will only trigger if the *specific* number is in the list.

Comment: I've added more detail

Comment: You might would want to use regex. As a dirty fix, convert the number to string and append a space before the `if` condition. <- This is a dirty fix which will only work in your case.

Comment: You might also split the string with space and index the 0th element and compare for a match.

Comment: Using regex seems to be the most legit way to do it

Comment: You have integer at the beginning of your sentence. You can do something like 
temp = item.split(' ') and which is going to split the sentence based on spaces between words and store it as a list in variable 'temp'. Then simply check if num == temp[0]

Comment: @SprungYetStrung upu may consider accepting an answer that helped you understand and solve your problem: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work cheers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took the super simple approach of splitting each item in the list and querying the first.

```
num = 2

list = ['2 dogs play', '4 dogs play', '22 dogs play', '24 dogs play', '26 dogs play']

for item in list:
    number_of_dogs = int(item.split(' ')[0])
    if number_of_dogs == num:
        print('Doing something!')
```

The code is very simplistic and only works if each item in the list starts with the number followed by a space.

Comment: This worked! I don't know regex yet, so this helped

Comment: I'm learning too, regex is VERY confusing at times. I'm glad the provided answer was of some help.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:**

Change your function to:

```
for item in list:
    #  Since it's obvious you're checking a string for a number (in string form), you need 
    #  to make sure a space comes after the number (at the beginning of the string) in order
    #  to avoid incomplete matches.
    if item.startswith(num, beg=0, end=len(num)):
        ...
        func_do(item)
```

**Results:**

A)

```
['2 dogs play', '4 dogs play', '22 dogs play', '24 dogs play', '26 dogs play']
num = '2' #  input with no space trailing
```

Output using this method is the result of `func_do('2 dogs play')`

B)

```
['2 dogs play', '4 dogs play', '22 dogs play', '24 dogs play', '26 dogs play']
num = '2 ' #  input with space trailing (user hit spacebar and we didn't `trim()` the input)
```

Output using this method is still the result of `func_do('2 dogs play')`

**Beware:**

Sanitize your input, if you use any other method provided so far (or any method that checks for spaces following the input) you will have to be wary of a user entering a number with a space after it (or before it).

Use `num = input().strip()` or:

```
num = input()
num = num.strip()
```

**ALSO:** This answer also obviously relies on the user-input string that you're trying to match residing at the beginning of the `item` strings from your `list`.

Comment: Sadly, it doesn't help with 22. There's a space after 22, so it detects 22 as well.

Comment: Ah true. I'll fix it... EDIT: Fixed :)

Comment: @SprungYetStrung Let me know if it works for you :)

Comment: It didn't seem to work for me. I have a more complicated code than what I posted, but I figured out a way. Thanks!

Comment: @SprungYetStrung glad we could help!

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the `digits` from the `item` and then check if it is `equal` to `num`:

Using regex:

```
import re

uList = ['2 dogs play', '4 dogs play', '22 dogs play', '24 dogs play', '26 dogs play']
num = int(input("Enter a num: "))

for item in uList:
      if num == int((re.findall(r'\d+', item))[0]):
         print(item)
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
Enter a num: 2
2 dogs play

Process finished with exit code 0
```

**EDIT**:

Using `split()`:

```
uList = ['2 dogs play', '4 dogs play', '22 dogs play', '24 dogs play', '26 dogs play']
num = input("Enter a num: ")   # no conversion to int here

for item in uList:
     if num == item.split(' ')[0]:  # split and get the digits before space
         print(item)
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
Enter a num: 22
22 dogs play

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: I was going to go this route, and this may be the best route for his actual purpose. Good explanation of regex method of solving (+1)

Answer (score 1):

There will be many ways to solve this problem, one way using `regex` is :

```
import re

for item in a:
   if re.search("^"+num+" ", item):
        print(item) 
        # Cool logic goes here
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 num= raw_input("enter the number that you want to check")
   if(num==item.split(' ', 1)[0])
   ...do something
```

that will check if the number exists in the list given that the number comes first in the list 
 
If you want to explicitly compare it to an int then the other provided answers are what you are looking for.